# Authentication for only first time in a flutter app using phone number

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am new to mobile app development. I am trying to build an app that requires users to register with phone number. I am doing the authentication using Firebase. I have been able to register user with phone number. But, i want app to register user for the first time and upon further loading, homepage should be displayed. Also if the user changes his phone number in the mobile device then he should be again required to register with new phone number.
I have tried something here...

```
class _State extends State<MyAppPage> {
  String phoneNo;
  String smsOTP;
  String verificationId;
  String errorMessage = '';
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<void> verifyPhone() async {
    final PhoneCodeSent smsOTPSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResend]) {
      this.verificationId = verId;
      smsOTPDialog(context).then((value) {
        print('Sign in');
      });
    };
    try {
      await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: this.phoneNo, 
        timeout: const Duration(seconds:20), 
        verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
          print(phoneAuthCredential);
        }, 
        verificationFailed: (AuthException exceptio) {
          print('${exceptio.message}');
        }, 
        codeSent: smsOTPSent, 
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verId) {
          this.verificationId = verId;
        });
    } catch(e) {
      handleError(e);
    }
  }

  Future<bool> smsOTPDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Enter SMS Code'),
          content: Container(
            height: 85,
            child: Column(children: [
              TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  this.smsOTP = value;
                },
              ),
              (errorMessage != ''
                ? Text(
                    errorMessage,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  )
                : Container()
              )
            ]),
          ),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Done'),
              onPressed: () {
                _auth.currentUser().then((user) {
                  if(user != null) {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
                  }
                  else {
                    signIn();
                  }
                });
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      }
    );
  }

  signIn() async {
    try {
      final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verificationId, 
        smsCode: smsOTP,
      );
      final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
      final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
      assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
    }
    catch (e) {
      handleError(e);
    }
  }

  handleError(PlatformException error) {
    print(error);
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'ERROR_INVALID_VERIFICATION_CODE':
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
      setState(() {
        errorMessage = 'Invalid Code';
      });
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      smsOTPDialog(context).then((value) {
        print('Sign In');
      });
      break;
      default:
      setState(() {
        errorMessage = error.message;
      });
      break;
    }
  }
```

The UI is as follows..

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
        return Scaffold(    
            appBar: AppBar(    
            title: Text('Phone Authentication'),    
            ),    
            body: Center(    
            child: Column(    
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,    
                children: <Widget>[    
                Padding(    
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),    
                    child: TextField(    
                    decoration: InputDecoration(    
                        hintText: 'Enter Phone Number Eg. +910000000000'),    
                    onChanged: (value) {    
                        this.phoneNo = value;    
                    },    
                    ),    
                ),    
                (errorMessage != ''    
                    ? Text(    
                        errorMessage,    
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),    
                        )    
                    : Container()),    
                SizedBox(    
                    height: 10,    
                ),    
                RaisedButton(    
                    onPressed: () {    
                    verifyPhone();    
                    },    
                    child: Text('Verify'),    
                    textColor: Colors.white,    
                    elevation: 7,    
                    color: Colors.blue,    
                )    
                ],    
            ),    
            ),    
        );    
    }
```

The problem is that firebase authenticated new user for the first time using phone number in the device, but it again asked for phone number when reopening app. Also on providing phone number firebase did not send OTP as user is already authenticated. 
I will be grateful for your help. Thanks in advance..